# Is Face Detection needed before doing annotation - Image Processing

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, annotations, face-detection

I need to annotate frontal (or near frontal) images using openCV. I'm currently going through the OpenCV manual and the book "Mastering OpenCV". This is the first time I'm using OpenCV and due to that I'm little bit confused with annotation and face detection.

I need to mark about 25 points in the human face. The required points are there in eyes, mouth, nose, eyes, ears .My question is :

Is it necessary to detect the face first, and then eyes, eyebrows, mouth, nose, ears. Is it the case that then only I can proceed with annotation. The reason why I'm asking this is that I'll be doing the annotation manually. So that, obviously I can see where the face is and then eyes, nose etc. I don't see the point of detecting the face first.
Can someone explain whether face detection is really needed in this case ?

According to the book "Mastering openCV" , I need to do the following step-by-step.

```
    (1) Loading Haar Detector for face Detection
    (2) Grayscale colour conversion
    (3) Shrinking the image
    (4) Histogram Equalization 
    (5) Detecting the face
    (6) Face preprocessing to detect eyes, mouth, nose etc.
    (7) Annotation
```

Answer (score 0):

Face detection allows a computer algorithm to search an image much much faster for the features like eyes & mouth.

If you are annotating the image yourself then it is of course much quicker just to annotate the wanted features and ignore unwanted ones.

Answer (score 0):

No, You don't need to annotate landmarks for face detection, Opencv provide you by some functions to detect faces, using some already trained models using Haar Cascades classifiers, prepared in opencv package as xml files, you just need to call them as explained [here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)

Annotation of images by some predefined landmarks is used to detect facial expression, and some facial details as estimation of head pose in the space, for these purposes [AAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_appearance_model), ASM models are used.

As well, annotating images is a step to train a model, for that you may use a lot of universal annotated databases, available on internet, whereas your test images don't need to be annotated